# How to convert linux module file (*.ko) to object file (*.o)?

Tags: linux, module

Is it possible to do that? And if yes, how to do?
Thanks!

BR

Comment: What purpose would this serve?

Comment: I got a wifi usb driver file (a.ko) which can work for vendor's image (Linux 2.6.32). But the one I compiled (b.ko) cannot work well for my image (Linux 2.6.32). So I think maybe I can convert the a.ko file back to a.o file and then use modpost to convert it to a2.ko: which could run on my image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

You can't simply convert a loadable module into a statically compiled driver.
Moreover, you *certainly* can't take a binary and use it in a different kernel version.

The kernel is very touchy about modules. To get a module to load it must be built against the same source tree, with the same configuration and using the same compiler as the kernel itself.

Comment: The vendor's "user manual" says it gives us the same Linux kernel source code, and I use the default configuration for compilation of Linux kernel. And I also downloaded the same version of wifi driver source code for compilation of the kernel module. But the result is that vendor's a.ko cannot be inserted into my kernel image, and my b.ko cannot work well...

However, thank you for your reply and clarification! Now it is clear for me.